# Swift: Event for when node leaves SKCameraNode's view?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skcameranode

Suppose:

- you have an `SKSpriteNode`, *node*, off doing its own thing
- you have implemented an `SKCameraNode`, *cam*, to dictate what the player can see
- *node* has the function:

```
func onScreen(camera:SKCameraNode) -> Bool {
    if camera.contains(self) { return true } 
    else { return false } 
}
```

**Question**
How can one add an event listener to *node* so that when *node* transitions from within the camera's view to out of the camera's view, it triggers or calls a function?

[This](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/05/swift-events.html) looks a bit complicated....

Comment: juSt use an if statement in update. check the frame boundaries of node against frame boundary of camera

Comment: @Fluidity works, but not the question. The question is about making an event :)

Comment: then use KVO. node is already an NSObject. This is kind of what update and friends were made for ;)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html.   assign the kvo to the nodes position... check it plus or minus its width and height bounds against camera.frame min and max bounds

Comment: There's something odd about this question. The `if camera.contains(self){...}` satisfies (seemingly) the criteria of the question. It triggers/calls a function when node transitions from one state to another. Right now they're only returns, but they could be anything. Including calling a function.

Comment: You have just the solution to your question code.Not only you don't need a protocol/delegate but making a events collector in this situation is a waste of time, cpu and memory. Especially because you must ask to yourself: what kind of information I need to collect? The tons of CGPoints positions assumed by my node when it's out of the camera? Why? You can simply call a function when your node is out of camera and handle your code there in that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add PhysicsBodies to your nodes, and "special boundary" nodes around your camera, then you can use your physics delegate to get notified if your nodes intersect the boundary nodes.